# Cannot add mapkey icon to L.easyButton in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to add an icon from mapkey to `L.easyButton` using the following code, but I am getting the error below.

```
var menuButton = L.easyButton({
    states: [{
        stateName: 'show-menu',
        icon: L.icon.mapkey({icon:"bars",color:'#000000',background: false,size:25}),
        title: 'Show Menu',
        onClick: function (btn, map) {
            menu.options.button = btn;
            menu.show();
            btn.state('hide-menu');
        }
    },{
        stateName: 'hide-menu',
        icon: 'fa-star',
        title: 'Hide Menu',
        onClick: function (btn, map) {
            menu.hide();
            btn.state('show-menu');
        }
    }],
    id: 'styles-menu',
});
menuButton.addTo(map);
```

### Error:

```
TypeError: ambiguousIconString.match is not a function
```

Do I need to add another type of icon or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.easyButton` accepts a [range of options for icons](http://danielmontague.com/projects/easyButton.js/v1/examples/#icon-options), but an `L.icon` object is not one of them. `L.icon` objects are for defining *marker* icons in Leaflet. It does not appear that you are defining a marker icon.

I would try using the actual icon class in a `<span>` for the `icon` property. For example:

```
var menuButton = L.easyButton({
    states: [{
        stateName: 'show-menu',
        icon: "<span class='mki mki-bars'></span>",
        title: 'Show Menu',
        /* ... your other code below ... */
    }]
});
```

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/63prkm5z/) using JSFiddle. You can see the menu button beneath the +/- buttons on the top left of the map.

Note that I did not build a menu, so clicking the menu button will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

`L.easyButton` doesn't take a `L.icon` argument. Your second use is correct, it can take a Font Awesome icon name. A plain HTML icon could work for you here - see http://danielmontague.com/projects/easyButton.js/v2/examples/#icon-options